# Dynamic soql reference JigsawCompanyId field

Tags: dynamic-soql

In dynamic Soql  when I try to query **JigsawCompanyId** , it queries null.name
for ParentID I queried parent.name, like wise for **JigsawCompanyId** how should i query

```
SELECT Name,AccountNumber,ParentId,Parent.Name, JigsawCompanyId,null.Name FROM Account
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References to the `JigsawCompanyId` are fairly sparse. About the only thing I could find on it was in the [Salesforce Field Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Account.htm) which only indicates it is a string of length 20.

I did find some more details on the seemingly related [`Account.Jigsaw`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) field.

> References the ID of a company in Data.com. If an account has a value in this field, it means that the account was imported from Data.com. If the field value is null, the account was not imported from Data.com. Maximum size is 20 characters. Available in API version 22.0 and later. Label is Data.com Key.
>
> The **Jigsaw** field is exposed in the API to support troubleshooting for import errors and reimporting of corrected data. Do not modify the value in the **Jigsaw** field.

It seems likely if you can see the field but the Jigsaw related fields are null then the data didn't originate from Data.com.

Comment: @dinesh If you have a new problem/question please create a new SFSE question for it. It keeps the Q&A nature of this site focused.